# RecordEditor - Field describes the layout for the line

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm using Record Editor to read a COBOL file. Works fine, one problem, though. The 3rd field (column, fixed width) describes the type of record. Doing this, also the layout for the rest of that line.

How can I tell RecordEditor to filter lines that apply to the selected layout?

For instance :

Check 6-9 for record type, set rest of column widths depending on that type :

```
001XXTYP1THISISSOMETEXT
002XXTYP22013FORMATISDIFFERENTSOMEVARIABLE
003XXTYP3FOOBLAHBLAHBAR
```

I set up RecordEditor and Copied the COBOL CopyBook. It all works fine.. BUT.. when I select a specific layout (TYP1 / TYP2 of TYP3) all records stay visible. So if I select TYP1, I also see the TYP2 and 3 lines. Can't find the setting for that.

Comment: Google turns up a lot of tools with the name "RecordEditor" or "Record Editor."  For instance, [this](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/Cobol.html), [this](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/Record02.htm), and [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/). A link to the home page of the tool that you are using would help us all.  (And might lead you to the answer to your question.)

Comment: David, both the listed entries are for the same product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thing - make sure you have record selection setup correctly; the RecordEditor works much better if you do.

The **Filter Function** is probably what you want. Options to look at are

1. **Filter Function** (it is the button to the right of the Find button on the toolbar) Filter allows you to create "views" of the file based on either RecordType or record content. [Filter Function](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/Record08.htm)
2. Prefered Layout - with the preferred Layout, The column Headings change to match the row selected via the cursor.
3. Single Record View (click the button to the Left of a line). In the latest version you can right click on the Tab to Undock the screen
4. (Latest Test  version only) Child Records (**Window** >>> **Show Child Record**). When selected, the Record Selected via the cursor on the Left hand side of the Screen is also displayed as a Single record on the Right hand of the screen.

---

Update (08/08/2013)

There was a better solution introduced as part of RecordEditor 0.95. 
There is now an example macro (**ViewForEachRecordType.js**) that will
display all the *Record-Types* as seperate views:

[image: Running Macro]

Once the macro has run, each *Record-Type* is displayed in a seperate view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, Record Editor seems to be a bit of free software. It looks to have reasonable documentation containing references to several things which should help you. I think you need to go through that documentation, with your specific set-up, and then update your question.

Comment: Kees; Along with what Bill mentioned, look to the Filter documentation.  It should do exactly what you are looking for.  http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/Record08.htm